# Running iOS UIAutomation as a post-action build script is return as a posix spawn error

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, bash, ios-ui-automation

I'm entirely new to using bash and Xcode build scripts and so my code is probably a jungle full of errors.

The idea here is to trigger the script below which will scrape the directory that it is saved in for any .js automation scripts. It will then send these scripts to instruments to be run one at a time. I found some nifty code that created time stamped files and so I used that to create a more meaningful storage system.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script should run all (currently only one) tests, independently from
# where it is called from (terminal, or Xcode Run Script).

# REQUIREMENTS: This script has to be located in the same folder as all the
# UIAutomation tests. Additionally, a *.tracetemplate file has to be present
# in the same folder. This can be created with Instruments (Save as template...)

# The following variables have to be configured:
#EXECUTABLE="Plans.app"

# Find the test folder (this script has to be located in the same folder).
ROOT="$( cd -P "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# Prepare all the required args for instruments.
TEMPLATE=`find $ROOT -name '*.tracetemplate'`
#EXECUTABLE=`find ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator | grep "${EXECUTABLE}$"`
echo "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"
echo "$PRODUCT_NAME"
EXECUTABLE="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/"
SCRIPTS=`find $ROOT -name '*.js'`

# Prepare traces folder
TRACES="${ROOT}/Traces/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`"
mkdir -p "$TRACES"

printf "\n" >> "$ROOT/results.log"
echo `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` >> "$ROOT/results.log"

# Get the name of the user we should use to run Instruments.
# Currently this is done, by getting the owner of the folder containing this script.
USERNAME=`ls -l "${ROOT}/.." | grep \`basename "$ROOT"\` | awk '{print $3}'`

# Bring simulator window to front. Depending on the localization, the name is different.
osascript -e 'try
    tell application "iPhone Simulator" to activate
on error
    tell application "iOS Simulator" to activate
end try'

# Prepare an Apple Script that promts for the password.
PASS_SCRIPT="tell application \"System Events\"
activate
display dialog \"Password for user $USER:\" default answer \"\" with hidden answer
text returned of the result
end tell"

# Run all the tests.
for SCRIPT in $SCRIPTS; do
    echo -e "\nRunning test script $SCRIPT"
    TESTC="sudo -u ${USER} xcrun instruments -l -c -t ${TEMPLATE} ${EXECUTABLE} -e UIARESULTSPATH ${TRACES}/${TRACENAME} -e UIASCRIPT ${SCRIPT} >> ${ROOT}/results.log"
#echo "$COMMAND"
    echo "Executing command $TESTC" >> "$ROOT/results.log"
echo "here $TESTC" >> "$ROOT/results.log"
    OUTPUT=$(TESTC)

    echo $OUTPUT >> "$ROOT/results.log"
    echo "Finished logging" >> "$ROOT/results.log"
    SCRIPTNAME=`basename "$SCRIPT"`
    TRACENAME=`echo "$SCRIPTNAME" | sed 's_\.js$_.trace_g'`

    for i in $(ls -A1t $PWD | grep -m 1 '.trace')
    do
        TRACEFILE="$PWD/$i"
    done

    if [ -e $TRACEFILE ]; then
        mv "$TRACEFILE" "${TRACES}/${TRACENAME}"
    fi

    if [ `grep " Fail: " results.log | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "Test ${SCRIPTNAME} failed. See trace for details."
        open "${TRACES}/${TRACENAME}"
        exit 1
        break
    fi

done

rm results.log
```

A good portion of this was taken from another Stack Overflow answer but because of the repository setup that I'm working with I needed to keep the paths abstract and separate from the root folder of the script. Everything seems to work (although probably not incredibly efficiently) except for the actual xcrun command to launch instruments.

```
TESTC="sudo -u ${USER} xcrun instruments -l -c -t ${TEMPLATE} ${EXECUTABLE} -e     UIARESULTSPATH ${TRACES}/${TRACENAME} -e UIASCRIPT ${SCRIPT} >> ${ROOT}/results.log"
echo "Executing command $TESTC" >> "$ROOT/results.log"
OUTPUT=$(TESTC)
```

This is turned into the following by whatever black magic Bash runs on:

```
sudo -u Braains xcrun instruments -l -c -t 
/Users/Braains/Documents/Automation/AppName/TestCases/UIAutomationTemplate.tracetemplate
/Users/Braains/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-
ekqevowxyipndychtscxwgqkaxdk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/ -e UIARESULTSPATH
/Users/Braains/Documents/Automation/AppName/TestCases/Traces/2014-07-17_16-31-49/ -e 
UIASCRIPT /Users/Braains/Documents/Automation/AppName/TestCases/Test-Case_1js
```

(^ Has inserted line breaks for clarity of the question ^)

The resulting error that I am seeing is:

```
posix spawn failure; aborting launch (binary == 
/Users/Braains/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-
ekqevowxyipndychtscxwgqkaxdk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/AppName).
```

I have looked all over for a solution to this but I can't find anything because Appium has a similar issue. Unfortunately I don't understand the systems well enough to know how to translate the fixes to Appium to my own code but I imagine it's a similar issue.

I do know that the posix spawn failure is related to threading, but I don't know enough about xcrun to say what's causing the threading issue.

Related info:
 - I'm building for the simulator but it'd be great to work on real devices too
 - I'm using xCode 5.1.1 and iOS Simulator 7.1
 - This script is meant to be run as a build post action script in xCode
 - I did get it briefly working once before I broke it and couldn't get it back to the working state. So I think that means all of my permissions are set correctly.

UPDATE: So I've gotten to the root of this problem although I have not found a fix yet. First of all I have no idea what xcrun is for and so I dropped it. Then after playing around I found that my Xcode environment variables are returning the wrong path, probably because of some project setting somewhere. If you copy the Bash command from above but replace Debug-iphoneos with Debug-iphonesimulator the script can be run from the command line and will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who happens across this the only solution I could find was to hardcode the script for the simulator.

I changed `EXECUTABLE="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/"` to be `EXECUTABLE="${SYMROOT}/Debug-iphonesimulator/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"`. This is obviously not a great solution but it works for now.